# understanding css specificity (a:active pseudo class)

Tags: css, selector, pseudo-class, css-specificity

I've got a set of unordered lists in my nav bar which link to other pages, I tried to set up my css so that all ul anchors have the same :active color.

So quite high up on my css doc I did the following:

```
/* will be overridden by more specific selectors as needed */
ul a:active{
    color: black;
}
```

This did not work. Nothing should be overriding it and forcing the active state to remain the same color.

I tried to make it more specific by adding another selector, see below:

```
.nav ul a:active{
    color: black;
}
```

It works, except I don't understand why this should be the case, I have not allocated a value to a:active anywhere else, so the first selector should do the trick.

I have, later in the stylesheet, added some rules for for the normal state of the anchors, see below:

```
.nav ul a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;

    /*padding-right: 0 !important; wtf is this */
    /* important overrides media queries */
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

I don't think this is overriding my first selector...

Answer (score 1):

This is because classes and pseudo classes have more weight in specificity. In order of most to least specific in your case:

- `.nav ul a:active`: 2 classes (including 1 pseudo class)
- `.nav ul a`: 1 class + 2 elements
- `ul a:active`: also 1 (pseudo)class + 2 elements, but earlier in your style sheet, so it has less specificity

Hopefully this explains why adding the `.nav` does make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

According to the specifications in [W3C Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity):

- count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a)
- count the number of **class selectors**, attributes selectors, and **pseudo-classes** in the selector (= b)
- count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector (= c)
- ignore the universal selector

**Examples:**

```
*               /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 */
LI              /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
UL LI           /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
UL OL+LI        /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
H1 + *[REL=up]  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
UL OL LI.red    /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */
LI.red.level    /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 */
#x34y           /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
#s12:not(FOO)   /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> specificity = 101 */
```

---

So when selectors have an equal specificity, the last rule is the one that counts, which is what's happening in your case.

**Breakdown of your selectors:**

Le's do the math:

- First selector group: two type selectors (c) `ul` & `a` and one pseudo-class (b) `:active`
- Second selector group: one class-selector (b) `.nav` and two type selectors (c) `ul` & `a`.

The end result is equal specificity:

```
ul a:active     /* a=0 b=1 c=2 -> specificity =  12 */
.nav ul a       /* a=0 b=1 c=2 -> specificity =  12 */
```

**Helpful resources:**

- W3C Selectors Level 3: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity
- Specificity Calculator: http://specificity.keegan.st/
- CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the specific style looks for your website, but I can give you a general tip:

If you are using Google Chrome, you can use https://developer.chrome.com/devtools and then inspect the element to see from which selector (and which stylesheet) the element gets its specific properties.

You can also do this with Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools or Internet Explorer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

EDIT:

Also found a nice link where you can read more about specificity, since your goal is understanding it:

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: Exactly what I did. That's how I know that which selector got applied.